# Need to start VMs exclude specific VMs

Tags: azure, shell

I was starting the all vms using azure CLI command i.e;

```
az vm start --ids $(az vm list --query "[].id" -o tsv)
```

Now I need to start all vms except some specified 2 vms.. How to exclude that 2 vms using this command or else give some shell script command..

Answer (score 1):

```
az vm start --ids $(az vm list --query "[?(name != 'myVm2')  && (name != 'master')].id" -o tsv)
```

Comment: Thanks for your response...I have one doubt here if instead of two VMs names...i want to pass more than 10 VMs..How to do that?Can you please help me for this..

Comment: do you have any specific naming convention for exclude

Comment: Thanks for your continuous response...We dont have any name conventions... we have to exclude random vm names..